# What is the character " generally called in \" escape sequence according to C standards?

Tags: c

A sequence of two or more characters like `\"` is called an escape sequence and the `\` character is called an escape character.
Does the second character (`"`) in the escape sequence has a general name?

Comment: `\\"` is not an escape sequence, it's an escape sequence plus a "

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would reference it as the escaped character

Comment: The character after the escape character in an escape sequence usually happens to be a special character, that is why it needs escaping. The role inside an escape sequence I would refer to as "the escaped character" or "the escaped special character".

Comment: @Yunnosch: It's tricky though. The escape sequence usually *toggles* between special and non-special, it doesn't uniformly move from special to non-special or vice-versa. For example, in `"Interior \" escaped"`, the `"` starts special (it normally delimits the string), and the `\ ` escapes it. Whereas in `"Split\nlines"`, `n` isn't special, and becomes so because you escaped it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I concede the point. The core is that the escaping makes a character an escaped character. Wether it is/was/becomes special or not.

Answer (score 2):

If I have to give it a name, I call it the "escape*d* character" (with "unescaped character" used for characters that aren't escaped, typically with the implication that they might need to be), but it's incredibly rare you need to refer to it.

Comment: Sounds pretty much as an opinion based answer (unless you can provide a reference...)

Comment: I think it stops being an opion-based question if everybody is of the same opinion (exceptions for jokers...).

Comment: @Yunnosch Well, there is a difference between "what it is called" and "what it should be called"

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Sure, call it opinion. Language is opinion. I can refer you to [C# tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_character_escapes.htm) and [Matlab error messages](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/435377-warning-escaped-character-u-is-not-valid) and other incidental uses of the phrase, but all I can really tell you is that it's the natural meaning of language; if one character performs an escape on another character, the other character is "escaped", and I've never heard any other name for it.

Answer (score 0):

It is called double quote:)

```
double quote "    \"
```

and with the backslash represents a simple escape sequence.

Also there are alphabetic escape sequences like for example `\n`.